# Upgrade error 18

Tags: upgrade

My system was give me option to upgrade to Ubuntu 18,
After acceptance it took about 1 hour to download and install, but during installation
it give show some errors and later failed to upgrade.

now  if i run sudo apt-get update as shown in the attached image_1[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XS4Jt.png)

and if I run sudo apt-get upgrade it give me error of some unmet dependencies, as show in image_2[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbjAb.png)
s

```
ajid@sajid-Inspiron-7737:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 obex-data-server : Depends: libmagickwand-6.q16-2 (>= 8:6.8.8.2) but it is not installable
 upstart-app-launch : Depends: upstart (>= 1.11) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).


and if i run sudo apt --fix-broken install it gives 
  ubuntuone-credentials-common urfkill url-dispatcher velocity x11proto-xinerama-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  obex-data-server
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  upstart-app-launch
The following packages will be upgraded:
  obex-data-server
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 362 not upgraded.
8 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/75.9 kB of archives.
After this operation, 250 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 449092 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing upstart-app-launch (0.3+14.04.20140411-0ubuntu1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 37, in <module>
    import click_package as click
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'click_package'
dpkg: error processing package upstart-app-launch (--remove):
 installed upstart-app-launch package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 upstart-app-launch
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Did you try: `sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade` ?

Comment: As the screenshot suggests your file sources.list is having some links of Trusty(14.04) and some of Bionic(18.04). So unmet dependencies is obvious. Try to edit sources.list and comment out the links having trusty or try a simpler GUI method. Go to Software and updates and select all the updates you want to receive, if needed change the server. This will refresh the list. Then try update and upgrade again. Let me know it helps.

Comment: Even i commented out the Trusty in /etc/apt/sources.list
Now i run "sudo apt-get update" and later "sudo apt-get upgrade"
I get this error
:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 upstart-app-launch : Depends: upstart (>= 1.11) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: and if i run sudo apt --fix-broken install, I get

Comment: if i run "sudo apt --fix-broken install", I get " (Reading database ... 446556 files and directories currently installed.)Removing upstart-app-launch (0.3+14.04.20140411-0ubuntu1) ...Traceback (most recent call last):File "/usr/bin/click", line 37, in <module>import click_package as click Module Not FoundError: No module named 'click_package'
dpkg: error processing package upstart-app-launch (--remove):
 installed upstart-app-launch package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1 Errors were encountered while processing: upstart-app-launch E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg

Comment: E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Since upgraded from Ububtu 14 to 18 facing this upgrade error,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077420/since-upgraded-from-ububtu-14-to-18-facing-this-upgrade-error)