# Since upgraded from Ububtu 14 to 18 facing this upgrade error,

Tags: upgrade, 18.04

pip3 is not working anymore to install click_package, I manually downloaded and installed click package for python 3.6 but didn't find click_pakage to download and install.
Can you please help me to solve this problem.

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 upstart-app-launch : Depends: upstart (>= 1.11) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

sajid@sajid-Inspiron-7737:bin$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  account-plugin-tools accountsservice-ubuntu-schemas antlr3 apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu  
......
......
qtdeclarative5-dev-tools qtdeclarative5-ofono0.2 qtdeclarative5-online-accounts-client0.1 qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-content1 ruby2.3 snapd-login-service system-image-common
  system-image-dbus ubuntu-application-api3-test ubuntu-download-manager ubuntuone-credentials-common urfkill x11proto-xinerama-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  upstart-app-launch
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 499 not upgraded.
After this operation, 236 kB disk space will be freed.

Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y

(Reading database ... 446556 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing upstart-app-launch (0.3+14.04.20140411-0ubuntu1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 37, in <module>
    import click_package as click
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'click_package'
dpkg: error processing package upstart-app-launch (--remove):
 installed upstart-app-launch package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 upstart-app-launch
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: sajid@sajid-Inspiron-7737:~$ sudo apt-get purge python3-click-package python3-click click
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'python3-click' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 upstart-app-launch : Depends: upstart (>= 1.11) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
sajid@sajid-Inspiron-7737:~$

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the corresponding `python3-click-package`, `python3-click`, `click` packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge python3-click-package python3-click click
```

and then resume package installation and installing upgraded package dependencies:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: sajid@sajid-Inspiron-7737:~$ sudo apt-get purge python3-click-package python3-click click
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'python3-click' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 upstart-app-launch : Depends: upstart (>= 1.11) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
sajid@sajid-Inspiron-7737:~$

Comment: in Synaptic Package Manager.
upstart-app-lanch,    (version)0.3+14.04.20140411-0ubuntu1 (Description) Upstart job for launching Application, Has broken link.
I tried to remove it but it fails.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by manually removing the click by using the below commands.

sudo rm /usr/bin/click

sudo apt-get --fix-broken install

Than I used

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

Now everything looks OK